# Top Level Widget Not appearing above the Main widget in customtkinter/tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter, toplevel

I am using a top level widget in customtkinter to show an error, but the top level widget goes below the main widget so the user doesn't end up noticing the error. How can I make the top level widget a priority and make it appear in front of the main widget.

here's an example of what's happening-

```py
import customtkinter
    
app=customtkinter.CTk()

if: #something happens
  #do normal function
else: #error happens
  err=customtkinter.CTkToplevel()
  err.geometry("350x100")
  err.title("Error")     
  err.resizable(False,False)
  err.state("normal")
  err.anchor("center")

app.mainloop()
```

this new top level window is appearing below the main window.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: When I fix  your code so that it's runnable, the error message appears on top of the root window for me.

Comment: You want the error message in the Toplevel widget. So, algorithm should be like `if something wrong, then open Toplevel`. You have written the other way around.

Comment: Make the toplevel a *transient* window of the root window using [`.wm_transient()`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M64), then the toplevel will always be in front of the root window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Make the toplevel a transient window of the root window using .wm_transient(), then the toplevel will always be in front of the root window."

Worked for me thanks!

used `toplevel.wm_transient(app)`

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you have declared this conditional statement.  If it were declared before the main window ie window = customtinker. CTk(), there are chances for the top level window to open first.

So the foolproof method is declaring the toplevel window inside a function say err_handle(). Another function which was triggered by the main window or it's widget should trigger the function err_handle only if any error occurs.